# Using an auth-cookie when local server and SPA running on different ports

Tags: node.js, angular, express, nestjs

I have a `nest.js` webserver listening on `localhost:3000` and an angular frontend served to `localhost:4200` (with dev server). These ports are the defaults. My authentication flow consists of sending an access-token in a cookie to the frontend which doesn't get send back on subsequent calls because of different domain issues by the different ports. Can I overcome this issue somehow? I understand that if I don't run `npm serve` for the angular application only `npm run build` then a development server won't be started and I can serve the static files with `nest.js` which would solve the domain issue for the cookie, but this way I would loose watch mode and hot reloading for angular. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you manage to get this to work somehow? I'm in the same situation with the NestJS server running on a different port the my web app, and can't get cookies to get stored in chrome

Comment: Hi, late answer, sorry, in a really simple example where the frontend runs on 8080 and the server on 3000, by setting the following headers on the server and using `withCredentials: true` for xhr/axios, did the trick
    `app.use(function (req, res, next) {
        res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://127.0.0.1:8080')
        res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET')
        res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true)
        next()
    })`

Answer (score 0):

Your nest.js webserver needs to set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, so that the browser running the frontend doesn't complain about communicating with that host.